# How to calculate the two different tables using javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is my view page code:
When i entered the order no it fetch the two table data from the table using ajax code.In the first table when i tried to change the qty value it will multiply with rate and show it in the total column that i have done.
My problem is when i change the qty of first table it should be multiply with wgt/q of the second table and show it in the weight of second table column.
I don't how to do with second table calculation please help me to solve this problem
[image]

This is the ajax code that i have used to fetch the data from the table
My ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#orderno').on('input change',function(){
         var orderno = $("#orderno").val();
          var supplier = $("#supplier").val();
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>Inventory/Sales_fetch",
        data: {
                orderno:orderno
        },
        datatype: 'json',   
        success: function (data) {
       var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
       if(supplier == res.pname){
            fetch();
            item_type();
            $('#pono').val(res.pono);
            $('#podate').val(res.podate);
            $('#pname').val(res.accName);
            $('#bname').val(res.accName);       
            $('#text').val(res.addrs);  

     }
     else{
        alert("Invalid Order No for this Party");
     }     
        }
        });
    });
}); 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch() {
         var orderno = $("#orderno").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>Inventory/Billfetch",
        data: {
                orderno:orderno
        },
        datatype: 'json',   
        success: function (data) {
        $('#Product_Name_div').html(data); 
    }
});
 }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function item_type(){
         var orderno = $("#orderno").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>Inventory/itemfetch",
        data: {
                orderno:orderno
        },
        datatype: 'json',   
        success: function (data) {
        $('#itemtype').html(data); 
    }
});
 }
</script>
```

My  Model code:

```
function fetch_item1($orderno){
 $this->db->where("orderno",$orderno);
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->join('item_master', 'item_master.id = order_item.itname', 'left');
  $this->db->from('order_item');
  $query_result = $this->db->get()->result();

  $output = '<center><table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-xxs" id="tb2">  

  <tbody>';            

      if($query_result !='false'){
       $i=0; 

foreach ($query_result as $key => $value) { 

$output .='<tr> 
<td><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" id="remove"></span></a></td>
<td><input style="width:50px" name="sno[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" value="'.$value->sno.'" ></td> 
<td><input style="width:50px" name="rate[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs rate" value="'.$value->rate.'" ></td> 
<td><input style="width:250px" name="itemname[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" value="'.$value->itemname.'" ></td> 
<td><input style="width:80px" name="qty[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs qty" value="'.$value->qty.'" id="qty_'.$i.'" onchange="calculate('.$i.')"></td> 
<td><input style="width:80px" name="unit[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" > 
<td><input style="width:90px" name="total[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs total" value="'.$value->tot.'"> </td> 
<td><input style="width:150px" name="desc[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" > </td> 
<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" class="addMore" title="Add More Person"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></td>
</tr>'; 
$i++;
}
$output .="</tbody>
</table></center>";
echo $output;
}
}
function itemfetch($orderno){
 $this->db->where("orderno",$orderno);
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->join('item_master', 'item_master.id = order_item.itname', 'left');
  $this->db->join('item_type', 'item_type.name = item_master.itemname', 'left');  
  $this->db->from('order_item');
  $query_result = $this->db->get()->result();
  $output = '<center><table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-xxs" id="tb2">  

  <tbody>';            

      if($query_result !='false'){
       $i=0; 

foreach ($query_result as $key => $value) { 

$output .='<tr> 

<td><input style="width:120px" name="name[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" value="'.$value->itname.'" ></td> 
<td><input style="width:60px" name="wgtq[]"  type="text" class="form-control input-xs wgtq" value="'.$value->wgt.'" ></td> 
<td><input style="width:90px" name="wgt[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs wgt" > </td> 

</tr>'; 
$i++;
}
$output .="</tbody>
</table></center>";
echo $output;
}
}
```

My Code for first table calculation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate(id){ 
    var tot = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var qty = document.getElementsByClassName("qty");
    var rate = document.getElementsByClassName("rate");
for(var i = 0; i < qty.length; i++)
{
        tot = parseFloat(qty[i].value) * parseFloat(rate[i].value);
        total += parseInt(tot);
        $(".total").eq(i).val(tot);     
}

$("#Total").val(total)
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide the `html` code as well?

Comment: These are fetched data from the table i am using ajax code for that to create table

Comment: @pensum i have updated my code check it

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot personally help you. I don't know about ajax yet. You just need to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code so that others can reproduce and test your situation locally. Hope someone will do!